# context.getImageData(x, y, 1,1).data; returning only zeros

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, encoding

I'm creating a simple javascript app that converts text to an image and vice versa. however, my decoder is only returning an array zeros, when it should be returning an array of all of the rgb values of the image.

here is the unfinished decoder function:

```
function read()
{
    colors=new
Array(parseInt(document.getElementById('height').value)*parseInt(document.getElementById('width').value))
    i=0;
    for(y=0; y<parseInt(document.getElementById('height').value); y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x<parseInt(document.getElementById('width').value); x++)
        {
            colors[i] = context.getImageData(x, y, 1,1).data;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: alright, i found out what the problem was, but now i have a new one:
i keep getting the error "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Comment: alright, so the problem is in importing the image

Comment: it's now "Image from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: So, I guess my question now is, how do I get around that thing?

Comment: There's no getting around cross-origin security--there is satisfying cross-origin security requirements. In production, you can host the images on the same domain as the webpage. While developing, you can put the image in the same folder as the .html file. Alternatively, you can host the image on a site that allows cross-origin sharing like imgur & dropbox.

Comment: Alright, thank you :)

Comment: Never mind, now it says it's tainted

Comment: ... Would another programming language work?

Comment: No...just satisfy CORS rules.